# How do you change the date format in Sitecore Experience Profile journey timeline?

Tags: xdb, experience-profile

Right now, if you click an outcome in the Sitecore Experience Profile journey timeline, the outcome details shows the time in the following format:  06.10.2016 14:49:55

Is it possible to change this to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format?

I am using Sitecore 8.1 Update 2 with xDB Cloud

Comment: Where is that timeline located? Is your question about a particular application within Sitecore, like the Experience Profile?

Comment: From the dashboard, select Experience Profile, select a contact, timeline appears on the top of the page (there is a toggle button for it).  Click on a visit in the timeline and a visit detail panel slides into view.  This is where I see the Euro-formatted dates.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, looks like the date formats are hard-coded in Sitecore.Cintel.Client.dll. Looks like you need to write a custom Transformer that uses its own TimeConverter for the views you would like to modify in the Experience Explorer. Here is a [post](http://developmentsitecore.blogspot.com/2016/10/custom-sitecore-intel-transformers-to.html) I wrote on how to do just that.

P.S: Just scroll to the bottom to get to the good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Experience Profile has a concept of client transformers that modify data before it's displayed. Each page can have its own transformer. The configuration for it is in *Sitecore.ExperienceProfile.Client.config*. Specifically in your case you would need to replace the transformer for *journey-detail-outcome* view.

1) Define a time converter and provide your custom date/time formatting.

```cs
class MyTimeConverter : TimeConverter
{
    public MyTimeConverter(Sitecore.Cintel.Client.Repository repository, Sitecore.Cintel.Client.ContextUtil contextUtil)
        : base(repository, contextUtil)
    {
    }

    public override string FormatDateTime(DateTime time)
    {
        return base.FormatDateTime(time, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); //can be read from config
    }
}
```

2) Define a `ResultSetExtender` that is used to apply transformations to the data returned by the Experience Profile. Custom time converter is one of the constructor parameters.

```cs
public class MyResultSetExtender : ResultSetExtender
{
    public MyResultSetExtender() : this(
        Sitecore.Cintel.Client.ClientFactory.Instance.GetResultSetHelper(),
        new MyTimeConverter(Sitecore.Cintel.Client.ClientFactory.Instance.GetRepository(), Sitecore.Cintel.Client.ClientFactory.Instance.GetContextUtil()),
        Sitecore.Cintel.Client.ClientFactory.Instance.GetTextConverter())
    {         
    }

    public MyResultSetExtender(
      Sitecore.Cintel.Client.Transformers.ResultSetHelper resultSetHelper, Sitecore.Cintel.Client.Transformers.TimeConverter timeConverter,
      Sitecore.Cintel.Client.Transformers.TextConverter textConverter)
      : base(resultSetHelper, timeConverter, textConverter)
    {
    }
}
```

3) Define an actual transformer for the view and supply the result set extender from the previous step.

```cs
public class MyOutcomeTransformer : Sitecore.Cintel.Client.Transformers.Contact.JourneyOutcomeDetailResultTransformer
{
    public MyOutcomeTransformer() : base(new MyResultSetExtender()) { }
}
```

4) Patch *Sitecore.ExperienceProfile.Client.config*.